# Best way to share Docker volume between different computers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using Docker along with the `jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres` and `postgres` images.

I have two developers who want to share the postgres data. I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to do this.

I've already figured out how to persist data locally using the `volumes` attribute in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    container_name: keycloak-postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes_from:
      - data

  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DATABASE: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR: postgres
      POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT: 5432
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin123
    links:
      - "db"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  data:
    container_name: keycloak-postgres-db-data
    image: cogniteev/echo
    command: echo 'Data Container for PostgreSQL'
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

One approach I'm thinking of includes create my own Docker image (using a Dockerfile and using `FROM cogniteev/echo`) of the volume and hosting it DockerHub. Commit and push changes to the volume data to DockerHub. I'd then have to update my `docker-compose.yml` file to grab that particular image instead of `cogniteev/echo`.

But I'm not sure what is the best thing to do in this situation.

Comment: Hello, I understand you want send a database prefilled with data to your developers. Explain well what you want to do with the data. Because looks like you want to share the datafile in a network shared path, so you can start one postgres by developer and concurrently share the data. And this is not practical